# Controller/Parameter syntax?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter and let's say i build a blog where `/posts` shows all posts, and `/posts/cool_news` shows the article called `cool_news`.

I know the first one would only need a controller called `Posts` and a function called `index()`. But how about the second example? how to get the second parameter which can be anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default routing:

You create another action in the Posts controller called `cool_news()`

If you want it to be passed as an argument to the `index()` action then you need to look at doing some custom routing.

This is untested but should look something like:

```
$route['posts/(:any)'] = 'posts/index/$1';
```

Comment: that routing is what i need, cool_news is a variable and can't make statis function for it.